# Are Meta StackExchange and Career Overflow "authentic"?

Tags: discussion

Are https://meta.stackexchange.com/ and http://careeroverflow.com/ part of the SE ecosystem? I definitely think Career Overflow isn't but better to confirm. And if they are, they (both) don't offer an option to connect other SE accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta Stack Exchange was the meta for the original Stack Exchange 1.0 system. If you look at the bottom for the contact address, you'll notice it's area51@stackoverflow.com. So it is part of our system, just somewhat defunct since SE1.0 is being phased out. There has been some back-and-forth about merging it with this Meta.

CareerOverflow has a contact address of team@careeroverflow.com, and is copyright careeroverflow.com at the bottom instead of "Stack Overflow Internet Services Inc.". It's likely they are one of the Stack Exchange 1.0 sites, which are not owned by Stack Overflow.

Comment: Stack Exchange 1.0 is when it was paid, is it? I'm new on SE.

Comment: CareerOverflow is an SE 1.0 site.  View source and you'll see `<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">`

Comment: @squill That seems to tell me that it's a Stack Exchange 0.9 site.

Comment: ...yeah.  As opposed to the new SE 2.0 stuff was my point.  Stick it in Excel and set to 0 decimal places.